# Aspnet Core 3.0 Razor Pages with EDGE browser

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-edge, razor-pages

VS2019, Windows 10 - 1903 x64

A totally new project.

Launch in Debug mode using IE, it goes to URL

```
http://localhost:52297/
```

But if I choose EDGE, it will goto:

```
file:///C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/VisualStudio/EdgeAdapter/e9805624/landingPage.html
```

And certainly it fails to open, because a lot of files cannot be found by referencing to a file path instead of URL.

Is this a bug? Any way to work around?

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem after I was upgraded to MS Edge Chromium - a forced upgrade that happened over night.

I fixed it like this:
Visual Studio > in tool bar row at the green triangle button (Run) > click the tiny dropdown arrow at the right edge of that > click Web Browser > click Microsoft Edge (2)

Yep, there was a 2 in parenthesis.   HTH.

NOTE: before the upgrade F5 always started by opening that landingpage file and then it would display the ASP.NET page.  So opening that C:\ file is not the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use VS 2019 and create ASP.NET CORE project on Windows 10 -1903 x64 machine.

I try to run the project in IE and Edge browser and found that Visual Studio launching the project properly in both browsers.

Here, It can be possible that something got corrupted on your side.

I suggest you to repair your Visual Studio application may help to fix the issue.

Than you can again try to create new project and launch it in Edge browser to verify whether it fix the issue or not.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, are you using ASPNET CORE 3.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using .NET core 3.0. https://i.postimg.cc/9XStjKLT/311.png